# Executing a cassandra insert query through Python multiprocessing queue

Tags: python, cassandra, queue, multiprocessing

I have a cassandra keyspace `sujata`.I am connecting to cassandra using python driver `cassandra.cluster`.The column family of `sujata` is `hello`.
Following is my code:-

```
from multiprocessing import Process,Queue
from cassandra.cluster import Cluster
import os
queue=Queue()
cluster = Cluster(['127.0.0.1'])
metadata = cluster.metadata
session = cluster.connect("sujata")

def hi():
    global session
    global queue
    while True:
        y=queue.get()
        if y=="exit":
            os._exit(0)    
        else:
            print y
            session.execute(y)

if __name__=="__main__":
    x=Process(target=hi)
    x.start()
    for i in xrange(10):
        z="INSERT into hello(name) VALUES('" + str(i) + "');"
        queue.put(z)
        if i==9:
            queue.put("exit")
    session.cluster.shutdown()
    session.shutdown()
```

In the table, i have a column `name` to which i want to insert the value of i.The insert query is passed through a queue.I am able to get the contents of queue.when I run the above code,the output is:-

```
INSERT into hello(name) VALUES('0');
```

The session.execute() is not working.
I am unable to understand why this is happening.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't have a cassandra machine, but I guess, It'll work once you move the connection part to the prcoess-function `hi()`. Like:

```
def hi():
    cluster = Cluster(['127.0.0.1'])
    metadata = cluster.metadata
    session = cluster.connect("sujata")
    global queue
    while True:
        y=queue.get()
        if y=="exit":
            os._exit(0)    
        else:
            print y
            session.execute(y)
```

Don't know why it's behaving like this, but I've seen `global` variables behaving oddly with new processes.

This is not the best way to do I guess. Because each time it'll connect to the same database which is redundant and need to be closed. I hope there might be a better answer.

***Edit 1:***

I didn't read the code properly. You are using `queue`. So the process `hi` will start once only and `queue` is being used to communicate between the processes. So the connection to the database will also be once only. You don't need the database connection in main process. So shifting that part to the Multiprocess Function is the best way.

Comment: This is working fine.but as you said I will wait for the better answer.

Comment: @sujata Creating the connection from the process function is a terrible anti-pattern

Comment: @zehelvion Can you please suggest a alternate way to do it??

Comment: @RatDon sure, there is no "great" way to do it but if you need multiple processes and want all processes to be able to write to Cassandra, you need to decide between having a limited amount of processes with a small number of connections or, having processes connect via a pipe to a single process responsible for querying the db that accepts requests via select over all these pipes.

Comment: @zehelvion Here that's what she's doing right? creating the connection from a single process which is meant to write to cassandra and every other process will provide data to this process via a pipe (in this case a `Queue`).

Comment: You are right. Missed the part where only one process is creating the connection. Can't upvote because the answer wasn't edited. Thanks for correcting me on this.